# Serial key in pdf document

Tags: ebook, security

I don't know if it is a question to be asked here, but there is: I'm writting a ebook and I'm gonna to sell it soon.

I'd sell it at Google Play Store, but here in Brazil they don't accept PayPal as payment (and many brazilian don't have a credit card), so I think that the best option is to sell it by myself.

I could sell it also at Amazon, but the Kindle format just sucks when you work with (a lot of) equations.

But, of course, there's a problem about sending the pdf file to the buyer. My friend suggested me to lock it with a serial key - like a software. Then a person could open it just in one or three computers. I know there's a package that lock the pdf file with a password (that I create), but I'd like to have a way that block this password when it's used a lot of times - really like a software.

Is it possible?

Do you have any other ideas to protect a pdf file?

I'm gonna take the copyright of my ebook here in Brazil and I know that I can't protect it totally, but I'm trying to do everything I can do to protect it.

There's also a brazilian site (www.hotmart.com.br) where you can publish anything you want and they say that, about pdf files, they print in each page the document number of that one who bought my ebook.

Thanks! :)

Comment: We do not put an explicit thanks in the question or answer, you can think other people by using upvotes.

Comment: It's just a part of my education. And I upvote when I it's worth for me.

Comment: @Masroor Think other people? Do you mean `thank`?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Oh goodness, I really wanted to mean thank, and yes, you _think_ of other people when you wanted to _thank_ them.

Comment: @mvfs314 Yes, definitely it is part of education for everybody. But not putting an explicit thanks in a question is a norm at this site. Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/why-is-saying-thank-you-in-question-undesirable) and other links it takes you to.

Comment: Oh God, the world would be a better place if people would edit our lives putting a "thank you" on it, not taking off. I just can't belive that I had a discussion about this!

Comment: @mvfs314 It is like this over here, and if we want to have another discussion on this, we can take it to [meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This has nothing to do with LaTeX... voting to close.

Comment: @Werner I'm sorry for this. Do you have any idea where can I get some information about this?

Comment: @mvfs, it's not quite square on, but take a look at http://security.stackexchange.com. There are some questions about securing PDFs. Base your question on what's there already and it will be less likely to get closed. Good luck,